# How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?

Tags: php

Say i have this PHP code:

```
$FooBar = "a string";
```

i then need a function like this:

```
print_var_name($FooBar);
```

which prints:

```
FooBar
```

Any Ideas how to achieve this? Is this even possible in PHP?

Comment: If you need this for anything but debugging, you're doing something severely wrong. What is your use-case?

Comment: Implementing an accurate function for this probably needs someone to hack the PHP Core. Comparing values, there might be a case where two vars are of the same value so it's a problem. There's no "good" way to do this I guess.

Comment: Good question. I needed the same for debugging.

Comment: +1 - I needed this for auto-generating XML or JSON response from a model PHP object. Having to wrap the object inside another named `rootName => modelObject` array just adds unnecessary depth to the response. Wish this was baked into the language's runtime reflection capabilities.

Comment: I also had a need for this in a logging function. I wanted to be able to do the following: log($didTheSystemBlowUp); To appear in the log file like: $didTheSystemBlowUp = 'not yet, but very soon';

Comment: Also this can be useful when calling var_dump() so when you call at same time on several variables you have not manually output var name to distinguish between outputs of vardupms.

Comment: I am trying to also print var names because I want to do multiple bind_param and don't know how to pass an array into a function. Probably a noob problem, but it does make me want to get variable names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the name of a variable? PHP - Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272030/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable-php-reflection)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could use [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) to find the name of a variable that has the same value as the one you're trying to find the name of. Obviously this will not always work, since different variables often have the same values, but it's the only way I can think of to do this.

Edit: get_defined_vars() doesn't seem to be working correctly, it returns 'var' because $var is used in the function itself. $GLOBALS seems to work so I've changed it to that.

```
function print_var_name($var) {
    foreach($GLOBALS as $var_name => $value) {
        if ($value === $var) {
            return $var_name;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Edit: to be clear, there is no good way to do this in PHP, which is probably because you shouldn't have to do it. There are probably better ways of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ahh. Been to slow ;-) Thought the same, but using $GLOBALS instead. So the identity comparison yields true for equals scalar values ($a = 'foo'; $b = 'foo'; assert($a === $b);)?

Comment: Actually now that I've tested my code, my code always returned 'var' because it's being used in the function. When I use $GLOBALS instead, it returns the correct variable name for some reason. So I'll change the above code to use $GLOBALS.

Comment: Yup, i realised but get_defined_vars() was enough ta.

Comment: There are lots of cases where this code won't behave as expected.

Comment: This code is HORRIBLY incorrect. Checking to see f the variable is the same as the one that's sent over by VALUE is a very dumb idea. Myriads of variables are NULL at any given point. Myriads are set to 1. This is just crazy.

Comment: Try your code with

$a = 10;
$b = 10;

print_r(print_var_name($b));

Comment: Won't work because there are many different kinds of "variables" whose names it would be nice to be able to discover: local variables inside functions, global variables, Defined constants, arrays, array elements, objects, class const properties, class static properties, "magic" predefined constants...

Comment: while this definitely doesn't work i many cases, it DOES work very well for situations where the variable names are more verbose, which is what good coding practice should reflect.  $a and $b are BAD names; useful, but BAD.  i've found this little utility function immensely useful with more verbose variable names and consequently: +1.

Comment: I would just add that I believe this is the most helpful answer, but looping through $_GLOBALS may cause a timeout as sometimes it is very large.

Answer (score 56):

I couldn't think of a way to do this efficiently either but I came up with this. It works, for the limited uses below.

*shrug*

```
<?php

function varName( $v ) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $vLine = file( __FILE__ );
    $fLine = $vLine[ $trace[0]['line'] - 1 ];
    preg_match( "#\\$(\w+)#", $fLine, $match );
    print_r( $match );
}

$foo = "knight";
$bar = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$baz = 12345;

varName( $foo );
varName( $bar );
varName( $baz );

?>

// Returns
Array
(
    [0] => $foo
    [1] => foo
)
Array
(
    [0] => $bar
    [1] => bar
)
Array
(
    [0] => $baz
    [1] => baz
)
```

It works based on the line that called the function, where it finds the argument you passed in. I suppose it could be expanded to work with multiple arguments but, like others have said, if you could explain the situation better, another solution would probably work better.

Comment: This works, but only if the function varName is defined in the same file as the variable to be found.

Comment: Here you find a better implementation that works over several includes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19788805/1069083

Answer (score 34):

You might consider changing your approach and using a variable variable name?

```
$var_name = "FooBar";
$$var_name = "a string";
```

then you could just

```
print($var_name);
```

to get

```
FooBar
```

Here's the link to the [PHP manual on Variable variables](https://www.php.net/variables.variable)

Comment: I have worked with a system that used variable variables extensively. Let me warn you, it gets really smelly really fast!

Comment: most of the cases the user want to get the name and value of a var. think "function debugvar($varname)" and he intend to call it "debugvar('foo')" so the debug will show "foo = 123". with variable variable they will get 'foo' is undefined.

Comment: just look at what you are actually doing. Right there in your example you actually CREATE a variable `$FooBar` with the value `a string` just read your manual. This is horrible imho. you never assign the variable `$FooBar` a value, but it is there. *OUCH*

Answer (score 30):

No-one seems to have mentioned the fundamental reasons *why* this is a) hard and b) unwise:

- A "variable" is just a symbol pointing at something else. In PHP, it internally points to something called a "zval", which can actually be used for multiple variables simultaneously, either because they have the same value (PHP implements something called "copy-on-write" so that `$foo = $bar` doesn't need to allocate extra memory straight away) or because they have been assigned (or passed to a function) by reference (e.g. `$foo =& $bar`). So a zval has no name.
- When you pass a parameter to a function you are creating a *new* variable (even if it's a reference). You could pass something anonymous, like `"hello"`, but once inside your function, it's whatever variable you name it as. This is fairly fundamental to code separation: if a function relied on what a variable *used* to be called, it would be more like a `goto` than a properly separate function.
- Global variables are generally considered a bad idea. A lot of the examples here assume that the variable you want to "reflect" can be found in `$GLOBALS`, but this will only be true if you've structured your code badly and variables aren't scoped to some function or object.
- Variable names are there to help programmers read their code. Renaming variables to better suit their purpose is a very common refactoring practice, and the whole point is that it doesn't make any difference.

Now, I understand the desire for this for debugging (although some of the proposed usages go far beyond that), but as a generalised solution it's not actually as helpful as you might think: if your debug function says your variable is called "$file", that could still be any one of dozens of "$file" variables in your code, or a variable which you have called "$filename" but are passing to a function whose parameter is called "$file".

A far more useful piece of information is where in your code the debug function was called from. Since you can quickly find this in your editor, you can see which variable you were outputting for yourself, and can even pass whole expressions into it in one go (e.g. `debug('$foo + $bar = ' . ($foo + $bar))`).

For that, you can use this snippet at the top of your debug function:

```
$backtrace = debug_backtrace();
echo '# Debug function called from ' . $backtrace[0]['file'] . ' at line ' . $backtrace[0]['line'];
```

Comment: There are some good answers already. So this is just being pessimistic even in the face of reality.

Comment: @a20 All the answers have heavy caveats about when they can be used, and when they will break; none is a simple lookup from any variable to its name, because that is in fact impossible. Some do a lot of funky reflection for debugging purposes, which is fine; however, my *opinion* stands that you're better off just outputting the line number and looking up the line of source yourself - or using an interactive debugger like XDebug.

Answer (score 27):

This is exactly what you want - its a ready to use "copy and drop in" function that echo the name of a given var:

```
function print_var_name(){
    // read backtrace
    $bt   = debug_backtrace();
    // read file
    $file = file($bt[0]['file']);
    // select exact print_var_name($varname) line
    $src  = $file[$bt[0]['line']-1];
    // search pattern
    $pat = '#(.*)'.__FUNCTION__.' *?\( *?(.*) *?\)(.*)#i';
    // extract $varname from match no 2
    $var  = preg_replace($pat, '$2', $src);
    // print to browser
    echo '<pre>' . trim($var) . ' = ' . print_r(current(func_get_args()), true) . '</pre>';
}
```

USAGE: print_var_name($FooBar)

PRINT: FooBar

> **HINT**
> Now you can rename the function and it will still work and also use the function several times in one line! Thanks to @Cliffordlife
> And I add a nicer output! Thanks to @Blue-Water

Comment: Cool, thanks for this. I modified the $pat line slightly to `$pat  = '#(.*)'.__FUNCTION__.' *?\( *?(.*) *?\)(.*)#i';` this way I don't care what this debug function is called, and I get exactly what is passed into the function ie $hello, or "hello" (I dropped the $ match for the variable passed in, in the same line)

Comment: Fantastic piece of code! Thanks! However, it does not seem to work in all instances. Result of testing on my ubuntu 18.04 with php 7.2.19: Does not work when used multiple times on the same line of code, irrespective if it is used in one or separate expressions, because then it returns the name of the last variable of the line. If it is used in the same expression but on separate lines it works. Used in different expressions on different lines it works.

Comment: also that function should be in one line without "var_dump" - with combination `print_var_name, echo, var_dump` send output `$variable); echo ' '; var_dump($variable`

Comment: Works great for debugging.

Comment: This is an incredibly creative solution. Excellent function! In addition, OP didn't specifically ask, because I gather he was isolating his problem for the question, however, I gather OP wants the value output as well. So to avoid writing anymore client-side code, one can replace the last line of the function with: `echo '<pre>' . trim($var) . ' = ' . print_r(current(func_get_args()), true) . '</pre>';` which outputs FooBar = a string, and also accounts for arrays.

Answer (score 17):

Lucas on PHP.net provided a reliable way to check if a variable exists. In his example, he iterates through a copy of the global variable array (or a scoped array) of variables, changes the value to a randomly generated value, and checks for the generated value in the copied array.

```
function variable_name( &$var, $scope=false, $prefix='UNIQUE', $suffix='VARIABLE' ){
    if($scope) {
        $vals = $scope;
    } else {
        $vals = $GLOBALS;
    }
    $old = $var;
    $var = $new = $prefix.rand().$suffix;
    $vname = FALSE;
    foreach($vals as $key => $val) {
        if($val === $new) $vname = $key;
    }
    $var = $old;
    return $vname;
}
```

Then try:

```
$a = 'asdf';
$b = 'asdf';
$c = FALSE;
$d = FALSE;

echo variable_name($a); // a
echo variable_name($b); // b
echo variable_name($c); // c
echo variable_name($d); // d
```

Be sure to check his post on PHP.net: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

Comment: How do you obtain the current scope in array form?

Comment: Nice! For me only missing is `break;` when found equal in foreach + I did usable basic structure to automatically get var_name also if defined inside function. If you are often Copy&Paste or have better idea to improve it, use `variable_name( $variable, ( empty(__FUNCTION__) ? false : get_defined_vars() ) );`

Comment: This is probably the fastest and cleanest way to do the job, debugging likely includes performance issues.
The function should return directly in the foreach loop instead of just assigning without interruption. Given the GLOBALS can be large that can be quite a performance improvement.

Answer (score 15):

I made an inspection function for debugging reasons.  It's like print_r() on steroids, much like Krumo but a little more effective on objects.  I wanted to add the var name detection and came out with this, inspired by Nick Presta's post on this page.  It detects any expression passed as an argument, not only variable names.

This is only the wrapper function that detects the passed expression.
Works on most of the cases. 
It will not work if you call the function more than once in the same line of code.

This works fine:
 die(**inspect(**$this->getUser()->hasCredential("delete")**)**);

inspect() is the function that will detect the passed expression.

We get:      *$this->getUser()->hasCredential("delete")*

```
function inspect($label, $value = "__undefin_e_d__")
{
    if($value == "__undefin_e_d__") {

        /* The first argument is not the label but the 
           variable to inspect itself, so we need a label.
           Let's try to find out it's name by peeking at 
           the source code. 
        */

        /* The reason for using an exotic string like 
           "__undefin_e_d__" instead of NULL here is that 
           inspected variables can also be NULL and I want 
           to inspect them anyway.
        */

        $value = $label;

        $bt = debug_backtrace();
        $src = file($bt[0]["file"]);
        $line = $src[ $bt[0]['line'] - 1 ];

        // let's match the function call and the last closing bracket
        preg_match( "#inspect\((.+)\)#", $line, $match );

        /* let's count brackets to see how many of them actually belongs 
           to the var name
           Eg:   die(inspect($this->getUser()->hasCredential("delete")));
                  We want:   $this->getUser()->hasCredential("delete")
        */
        $max = strlen($match[1]);
        $varname = "";
        $c = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
            if(     $match[1]{$i} == "(" ) $c++;
            elseif( $match[1]{$i} == ")" ) $c--;
            if($c < 0) break;
            $varname .=  $match[1]{$i};
        }
        $label = $varname;
    }

    // $label now holds the name of the passed variable ($ included)
    // Eg:   inspect($hello) 
    //             => $label = "$hello"
    // or the whole expression evaluated
    // Eg:   inspect($this->getUser()->hasCredential("delete"))
    //             => $label = "$this->getUser()->hasCredential(\"delete\")"

    // now the actual function call to the inspector method, 
    // passing the var name as the label:

      // return dInspect::dump($label, $val);
         // UPDATE: I commented this line because people got confused about 
         // the dInspect class, wich has nothing to do with the issue here.

    echo("The label is: ".$label);
    echo("The value is: ".$value);

}
```

Here's an example of the inspector function (and my dInspect class) in action:

http://inspect.ip1.cc

Texts are in spanish in that page, but code is concise and really easy to understand.

Comment: errrm, doesn't that rely on you having the NuSphare debugger installed?

Comment: I posted a simplified version of this code there.  Also I modified this answer.  It should run on every PHP5 implementation now.

Comment: Ingenuity like this is why I smile every time I see people say "can't be done" or "not possible", which includes even Rasmus himself in this case. Kudos to Sebastián and anyone else that may have contributed to this answer.

Comment: Thanks Night Owl, but I insist that this is not bullet proof (as the answer states, it will fail if my "inspect()" function is called more than once in a single line!).  I would never use this in production.  It's only for a debugging inspector function that should never reach the production server.

Answer (score 8):

From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php#49997)

@Alexandre - short solution

```
<?php
function vname(&$var, $scope=0)
{
    $old = $var;
    if (($key = array_search($var = 'unique'.rand().'value', !$scope ? $GLOBALS : $scope)) && $var = $old) return $key;  
}
?>
```

@Lucas - usage

```
<?php
//1.  Use of a variable contained in the global scope (default):
  $my_global_variable = "My global string.";
  echo vname($my_global_variable); // Outputs:  my_global_variable

//2.  Use of a local variable:
  function my_local_func()
  {
    $my_local_variable = "My local string.";
    return vname($my_local_variable, get_defined_vars());
  }
  echo my_local_func(); // Outputs: my_local_variable

//3.  Use of an object property:
  class myclass
  {
    public function __constructor()
    {
      $this->my_object_property = "My object property  string.";
    }
  }
  $obj = new myclass;
  echo vname($obj->my_object_property, $obj); // Outputs: my_object_property
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Many replies question the usefulness of this. However, getting a reference for a variable can be very useful. Especially in cases with objects and *$this*. My solution works with objects, and as property defined objects as well:

```
function getReference(&$var)
{
    if(is_object($var))
        $var->___uniqid = uniqid();
    else
        $var = serialize($var);
    $name = getReference_traverse($var,$GLOBALS);
    if(is_object($var))
        unset($var->___uniqid);
    else
        $var = unserialize($var);
    return "\${$name}";    
}

function getReference_traverse(&$var,$arr)
{
    if($name = array_search($var,$arr,true))
        return "{$name}";
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
        if(is_object($value))
            if($name = getReference_traverse($var,get_object_vars($value)))
                return "{$key}->{$name}";
}
```

Example for the above:

```
class A
{
    public function whatIs()
    {
        echo getReference($this);
    }
}

$B = 12;
$C = 12;
$D = new A;

echo getReference($B)."<br/>"; //$B
echo getReference($C)."<br/>"; //$C
$D->whatIs(); //$D
```

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from answers above for many variables, with good performance, just one $GLOBALS scan for many

```
function compact_assoc(&$v1='__undefined__', &$v2='__undefined__',&$v3='__undefined__',&$v4='__undefined__',&$v5='__undefined__',&$v6='__undefined__',&$v7='__undefined__',&$v8='__undefined__',&$v9='__undefined__',&$v10='__undefined__',&$v11='__undefined__',&$v12='__undefined__',&$v13='__undefined__',&$v14='__undefined__',&$v15='__undefined__',&$v16='__undefined__',&$v17='__undefined__',&$v18='__undefined__',&$v19='__undefined__'
) {
    $defined_vars=get_defined_vars();

    $result=Array();
    $reverse_key=Array();
    $original_value=Array();
    foreach( $defined_vars as $source_key => $source_value){
        if($source_value==='__undefined__') break;
        $original_value[$source_key]=$$source_key;
        $new_test_value="PREFIX".rand()."SUFIX";
        $reverse_key[$new_test_value]=$source_key;
        $$source_key=$new_test_value;

    }
    foreach($GLOBALS as $key => &$value){
        if( is_string($value) && isset($reverse_key[$value])  ) {
            $result[$key]=&$value;
        }
    }
    foreach( $original_value as $source_key => $original_value){
        $$source_key=$original_value;
    }
    return $result;
}


$a = 'A';
$b = 'B';
$c = '999';
$myArray=Array ('id'=>'id123','name'=>'Foo');
print_r(compact_assoc($a,$b,$c,$myArray) );

//print
Array
(
    [a] => A
    [b] => B
    [c] => 999
    [myArray] => Array
        (
            [id] => id123
            [name] => Foo
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is interchangable, you must have logic *somewhere* that's determining which variable gets used. All you need to do is put the variable name in `$variable` within that logic while you're doing everything else.

I think we're all having a hard time understanding what you're needing this for. Sample code or an explanation of what you're actually trying to *do* might help, but I suspect you're way, **way** overthinking this.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have a valid use case for this.

I have a function cacheVariable($var) (ok, I have a function cache($key, $value), but I'd like to have a function as mentioned).

The purpose is to do:

```
$colour = 'blue';
cacheVariable($colour);
```

...

```
// another session
```

...

```
$myColour = getCachedVariable('colour');
```

I have tried with

```
function cacheVariable($variable) {
   $key = ${$variable}; // This doesn't help! It only gives 'variable'.
   // do some caching using suitable backend such as apc, memcache or ramdisk
}
```

I have also tried with

```
function varName(&$var) {
   $definedVariables = get_defined_vars();
   $copyOfDefinedVariables = array();
   foreach ($definedVariables as $variable=>$value) {
      $copyOfDefinedVariables[$variable] = $value;
   }
   $oldVar = $var;
   $var = !$var;
   $difference = array_diff_assoc($definedVariables, $copyOfDefinedVariables);
   $var = $oldVar;
   return key(array_slice($difference, 0, 1, true));
}
```

But this fails as well... :(

Sure, I could continue to do cache('colour', $colour), but I'm lazy, you know... ;)

So, what I want is a function that gets the ORIGINAL name of a variable, as it was passed to a function. Inside the function there is no way I'm able to know that, as it seems. Passing get_defined_vars() by reference in the second example above helped me (Thanks to Jean-Jacques Guegan for that idea) somewhat. The latter function started working, but it still only kept returning the local variable ('variable', not 'colour').

I haven't tried yet to use get_func_args() and get_func_arg(), ${}-constructs and key() combined, but I presume it will fail as well.

Comment: The very basic problem is that you're passing **values** into functions, not **variables**. Variables are temporary and particular to their scope. Often the variable name may not be the key you want to cache the value under, and often you'll restore it to a differently named variable anyway (as you do in your example). If you're really too lazy to repeat the name of the key to remember the variable by, use `cacheVariable(compact('color'))`.

Answer (score 1):

I have this:

```
  debug_echo(array('$query'=>$query, '$nrUsers'=>$nrUsers, '$hdr'=>$hdr));
```

I would prefer this:

```
  debug_echo($query, $nrUsers, $hdr);
```

The existing function displays a yellow box with a red outline and shows each variable by name and value. The array solution works but is a little convoluted to type when it is needed.

That's my use case and yes, it does have to do with debugging. I agree with those who question its use otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution based on `Jeremy Ruten`

```
class DebugHelper {

    function printVarNames($systemDefinedVars, $varNames) {
        foreach ($systemDefinedVars as $var=>$value) {
            if (in_array($var, $varNames )) {
                var_dump($var);
                var_dump($value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

using it

```
DebugHelper::printVarNames(
    $systemDefinedVars = get_defined_vars(),
    $varNames=array('yourVar00', 'yourVar01')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use compact() to achieve this.

```
$FooBar = "a string";

$newArray = compact('FooBar');
```

This would create an associative array with the variable name as the key.  You could then loop through the array using the key name where you needed it.

```
foreach($newarray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: Cool but you have to know the name of the variable to use it.  OP is looking to programmatically determine variable name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know variable name with it's value. You can use an associative array to achieve this.

use variable names for array keys:

```
$vars = array('FooBar' => 'a string');
```

When you want to get variable names, use `array_keys($vars)`, it will return an array of those variable names that used in your `$vars` array as it's keys.

Comment: Much slower than the more usual methods of declaring variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I did it

```
function getVar(&$var) {
    $tmp = $var; // store the variable value
    $var = '_$_%&33xc$%^*7_r4'; // give the variable a new unique value
    $name = array_search($var, $GLOBALS); // search $GLOBALS for that unique value and return the key(variable)
    $var = $tmp; // restore the variable old value
    return $name;
}
```

**Usage**

```
$city  = "San Francisco";
echo getVar($city); // city
```

**Note:** some PHP 7 versions will not work properly due to a bug in `array_search` with `$GLOBALS`, however all other versions will work.

See this https://3v4l.org/UMW7V

Comment: the idea is good, but it only works it the variable is global, which is not a good practice in most cases. When the variable is not global, it somehow returns `wp_did_header` instead of the variable name (php 7.4.33)

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined function in PHP that can output the name of a variable. However, you can use the result of `get_defined_vars()`, which returns all the variables defined in the scope, including name and value. Here is an example:

```
<?php
    // Function for determining the name of a variable
    function getVarName(&$var, $definedVars=null) {
        $definedVars = (!is_array($definedVars) ? $GLOBALS : $definedVars);
        $val = $var;
        $rand = 1;
        while (in_array($rand, $definedVars, true)) {
            $rand = md5(mt_rand(10000, 1000000));
        }
        $var = $rand;
         
        foreach ($definedVars as $dvName=>$dvVal) {
            if ($dvVal === $rand) {
                $var = $val;
                return $dvName;
            }
        }
         
        return null;
    }
 
    // the name of $a is to be determined.   
    $a = 1;
     
    // Determine the name of $a
    echo getVarName($a);
?>
```

Read more in [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php/)

Answer (score 1):

There is [an RFC for a `nameof()` function](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nameof) currently *under discussion* that would do what you are asking for. It's proposed to become part of [PHP 8.4](https://php.watch/versions/8.4/releases), while becomming a reserved word in [PHP 8.3](https://php.watch/versions/8.3/releases)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just build a simple function and TELL it?

```
/**
 * Prints out $obj for debug
 *
 * @param any_type $obj
 * @param (string) $title
 */
function print_all( $obj, $title = false )
{
    print "\n<div style=\"font-family:Arial;\">\n";
    if( $title ) print "<div style=\"background-color:red; color:white; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; margin:0; padding:10px; text-align:center;\">$title</div>\n";
    print "<pre style=\"background-color:yellow; border:2px solid red; color:black; margin:0; padding:10px;\">\n\n";
    var_export( $obj );
    print "\n\n</pre>\n</div>\n";
}

print_all( $aUser, '$aUser' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this but just decided to pass the name in, I usually have the name in the clipboard anyway.

```
function VarTest($my_var,$my_var_name){
    echo '$'.$my_var_name.': '.$my_var.'<br />';
}

$fruit='apple';
VarTest($fruit,'fruit');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and already answered but I was actually looking for this. I am posting this answer to save people a little time refining some of the answers.

Option 1:

```
$data = array('$FooBar');  

$vars = [];  
$vars = preg_replace('/^\\$/', '', $data); 

$varname = key(compact($vars));  
echo $varname;
```

Prints:

> FooBar

For whatever reason you would find yourself in a situation like this, it does actually work.

.
Option 2:

```
$FooBar = "a string";  

$varname = trim(array_search($FooBar, $GLOBALS), " \t.");  
echo $varname;
```

If `$FooBar` holds a unique value, it will print 'FooBar'. If `$FooBar` is empty or null it will print the name of the first empty or null string it finds.

It could be used as such:

```
if (isset($FooBar) && !is_null($FooBar) && !empty($FooBar)) {
    $FooBar = "a string";
    $varname = trim(array_search($FooBar, $GLOBALS), " \t.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

other use:

shrug

```
function varsToArrayAssoc(...$arguments){
  
    $bt   = debug_backtrace();
    $file = file($bt[0]['file']);
    $src  = $file[$bt[0]['line']-1];
    $pat = '#(.*)'.__FUNCTION__.' *?\( *?(.*) *?\)(.*)#i';
    $vars  =explode(',',substr_replace(trim(preg_replace($pat, '$2', $src)) ,"", -1));
    $result=[];
    foreach(func_get_args() as $key=>$v){
        $index=trim(explode('$',$vars[$key])[1]);
        $result[$index]=$v;
    }
    return $result;
}

$a=12;
$b=13;
$c=123;
$d='aa';

var_dump(varsToArrayAssoc($a,$b,$c,$d));
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this to detach user variables from global to check variable at the moment.

```
function get_user_var_defined () 
{
    return array_slice($GLOBALS,8,count($GLOBALS)-8);     
}

function get_var_name ($var) 
{
    $vuser = get_user_var_defined(); 
    foreach($vuser as $key=>$value) 
    {
        if($var===$value) return $key ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: @IMSoP Judging by the output of `print implode( ' ', array_keys( $GLOBALS ));` it looks like a mistaken assumption about the number of "default" globals.  On my system there are seven superglobals: $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_FILES, $_ENV, $_REQUEST, $_SERVER.  And there's also argv and argc.  So the offset should be 9.  And there's no point in specifying the third parameter (length) since the default is just to run to the end of the array anyway.

Answer (score -2):

It may be considered quick and dirty, but my own personal preference is to use a function/method like this:

```
public function getVarName($var) {      
  $tmp = array($var => '');
  $keys = array_keys($tmp);
  return trim($keys[0]);
}
```

basically it just creates an associative array containing one null/empty element, using as a key the variable for which you want the name.

we then get the value of that key using array_keys and return it.

obviously this gets messy quick and wouldn't be desirable in a production environment, but it works for the problem presented.

Comment: Thats the value of the variable, not the name of the variable.  As pointed out elsewhere the name isn't portable across function boundaries.

Comment: minus one because this function is literally does nothing but returning the trim($var);

Answer (score -3):

why we have to use globals to get variable name... we can use simply like below.

```
    $variableName = "ajaxmint";

    echo getVarName('$variableName');

    function getVarName($name) {
        return str_replace('$','',$name);
    }
```

Comment: Because the OP does not know the variable name.  If he did, he wouldn't need a `getVarName()` function.  ;-)

Comment: This does not return the name of a variable as string, because `'$variableName'` is already a string, not a variable. If you can do this trick with `getVarName($variableName);`, you get an upvote :)

Answer (score -4):

I really fail to see the use case... If you will type print_var_name($foobar) what's so hard (and different) about typing print("foobar") instead?

Because even if you were to use this in a function, you'd get the local name of the variable...

In any case, here's the [reflection manual](http://www.php.net/oop5.reflection) in case there's something you need in there.

Comment: Print("foobar") will not handle other vars.

Comment: Use case: you have few debug points in the code returning dumping the same value. How do you know which one was executed first? Printing a label is very useful then.

Comment: Then you haven't done enough programming. Most languages I've come across have some way of doing this, usually simple.

Comment: @b01 I've done plenty. I'm perfectly aware there are many languages that allow this, but that by itself doesn't mean much. Many languages offer some way to do goto easily and that doesn't mean you should use it to avoid writing proper flow control. This is a similar case in my view. I don't doubt there are justifiable cases, and that's why I was wondering about proper use cases for it.