# PHP: Get name of variable passed as argument

Tags: php, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

#### problem

Sometimes, I need to to show name of variable passed as argument while debugging, can I get a name of `var` passed to function if it exists and value if it doesn't?

#### example

```
function foo($bar){
  print_variable_name($bar); //<- this part baffles me
}

foo ("Pure string."); //output " Pure string. "
foo ($argumentvariable); //output " argumentvariable "
```

#### solution

## ?

Comment: Sorry, looked on overflow, haven't seen it. Thank you Gumbo.