# object passed in parameter with its original names?

Tags: php, object

i want to use different objects inside the template. different objects are created on different section of the site.

currently my code is

```
public function notify ($template, $info)
{
    ob_start();
    include $template; 
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    //... more further code
}
```

as you see $info parameter. i dont want to use $info inside templates, but i was to use $photo, $admin or whatever is passed to it.

which i use like

```
// for feed
$user->notify('email_template_feed.php', $feed);

// for new photo - i would also like to use $user inside templates
$user->notify('email_template_photo.php', $photo);
```

how can i do that? cant use global, because is inside function and function is getting called dynamically on different locations/sections of the site, which can further extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503443/original-variable-name-passed-to-function).

**Solution 1**

Instead you could use an array and extract its values:

```
public function notify ($__template, array $info)
{
    ob_start();
    extract($info);
    include $__template; 
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    //... more further code
}
```

**Example 1**

if you call it with:

```
$user->notify('email_template_feed.php', array('feed' => $feed));
```

and inside the template `email_template_feed.php`:

```
...
<?=$feed?>
...
```

it will print:

```
...
FEED
...
```

**Solution 2**

You could also pass the name of the variable as third parameter:

```
public function notify ($template, $info, $name)
{
    ob_start();
    $$name = $info;
    unset($info);
    include $template; 
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    //... more further code
}
```

**Example 2**

You could then call it via:

```
$user->notify('email_template_feed.php', $feed, 'feed');
```

Comment: wanted some roboust way to do it. so much dont want to do array. but i have a feeling cant do it without it. :/

Comment: @Basit, it's not just a feeling.

Comment: cant we get the name of variable from php?

Comment: @Basit, no we can't, as explained in the very first line.