# How do I extract the parameters in a function call from source code?

Tags: php, debugging

I am creating a debugging/logging class for some of the scripts that i write.
Currently I have the following :

```
public function log()
{
        $funcArgs = func_get_args();
        $args = array_shift($funcArgs);
        $debug = '';
            $bt = debug_backtrace();
           // OK lets extract the data
            $file = $bt[0]['file'];
            $line = $bt[0]['line'];
            $function=$bt[0]['function'];
            $fileContents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            $fileLine = $fileContents[$line-1];
            unset($fileContents);
            $debug = 'File :' . $file . ' - Line :' . $line . ' - Command :'
                . $fileLine . ' -> ';
        foreach ($funcArgs as $index => $arg) {
                $output = print_r($arg, true);
            }
            echo $debug . $output."\n";
        }
}
```

This basically allows me to call the log method with a variable number of parameters and have each one logged (I have removed the formatting and actual log writing from the code to make it easier to read).

```
$test='goodby';
$log=new \loggy();
$log->log('hello', $test);
exit();
```

Outputs the following :

```
File :/var/www/public_html/index.php - Line :35 - Command :$log->log('hello', $test); -> hello
File :/var/www/public_html/index.php - Line :35 - Command :$log->log('hello', $test); -> goodby
```

I want to find a way to extract the fields that are passed to the log method, so i can get an output like:

```
File : public/index.php - Line 35 : String : hello
File : public/index.php - Line 35 : Var : $test : goodby
```

Any recommendations on the best way to extract the parameter names from the calling line of code?

Idea is to cut down on logging lines like :

```
$log->log('String ='.'hello', '$test='.$test);
```

I know i can do something like :

```
$paramStart=strpos($fileLine, $function)+4;
$paramEnd=strpos($fileLine, ')');
$paramLength=$paramEnd-$paramStart;
$string=substr($fileLine, $parmStart, $paramLength);
$params=explode($string, ',');
```

But that chunk of code is very unreliable and forces very strict rules on how and what can be on a line that calls the log method.

EDIT :

It has been suggested that : [original variable name passed to function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4503443/6870483)
Answers this question, but it still leaves the issue of separating the parameters from the source code :

```
debug($param1, "i love PHP scrip\'s", $param2, 'but I hate, trying to debug them! as it costs $\'s in time');
```

I can extract a string :

```
$param1, "i love PHP scrip\'s", $param2, 'but I hate, trying to debug them! as it costs $\'s in time'
```

from the source code, but cant find a way of reliably separating each of the parameters to give me an array like :

```
array(
    0 => '$param1',
    1 => 'i love PHP script`s',
    2 => '$param2',
    3 => 'but I hate, trying to debug them! as it costs $\'s in time'
);
```

As you can see, the above example means I can't just split the string on ',' and need to be able to take into account the escaped characters as well.

Comment: Check this out, https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Debug, not exactly what you want, but you can use `debug_backtrace()`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php  Or `func_get_args()` depending on exactly what you want.  My debugging class for example, will tell you exactly what line and file you used it on.  I got sick of losing `print_r` statements in my code.

Comment: IMO you are tilting at windmills. You should use existing debugging extensions like xdebug, which can give you an entire stackframe with all local variables. Trying to tease this apart in PHP itself seems like a lot of effort for little gain.

Comment: Hi deceze, yup xdebug would give me this as well, but that involves configuring xdebug and a frontend to read the data for every set of scripts that i create.  For bigger projects I do use xdebug, but for small scripts it can be a PITA.