# How to get variable name in PHP?

Tags: php

`func($name1)` should return `name1`

Is it possible?

Comment: In TCL you can do this easily.

Comment: first of all, why do you want to do it? please give the usecase. i cannot get the context fully.

Comment: Can you? Yes.  Should you? Absolutely not.

Comment: duplicate of [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a function that does it.

```
function var_name (&$iVar, &$aDefinedVars)
{
    foreach ($aDefinedVars as $k=>$v)
        $aDefinedVars_0[$k] = $v;

    $iVarSave = $iVar;
    $iVar     =!$iVar;

    $aDiffKeys = array_keys (array_diff_assoc ($aDefinedVars_0, $aDefinedVars));
    $iVar      = $iVarSave;

    return $aDiffKeys[0];
}
```

Call it like this

```
$test = "blah";
echo var_name($test,  get_defined_vars());
```

That will print out "test".

I originally found that function [over here](http://mach13.com/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php) You can also do it by iterating over the array returned by get_defined_vars(). That might be a bit easier to understand.

Comment: I tried this in CodePad (http://codepad.org/w11zjYUv) and it worked. People should vote this answer up. I wonder why the other answer with a simple "No" got way more up votes than this one...

Comment: People should think of this code necessity.
Think of array use if you need a key's name
But leave variable abstract.

Comment: "No" has more votes because it takes less time to type "no" than it does to test and describe a solution. Others come in after "no" is posted but before the answer is and vote up "no" because they don't know how and so assume it is therefore impossible. It'll work itself out hopefully :)

Comment: This involves copying the value of every variable in scope, which is pretty inefficient.  It should work, but it's not something I'd want to use.

Comment: And people are downvoting *this* answer? What's up with that?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to get the name of a variable in PHP.

When calling a function, that function will only receive the content of the variable, and not the "variable itself" -- which means a function cannot find out the name of the variable that was passed to it.

Comment: *"Vigorous writing is concise. A sentence should contain no unnecessary words, a paragraph no unnecessary sentences, for the same reason that a drawing should have no unnecessary lines and a machine no unnecessary parts. This requires not that the writer make all his sentences short, or that he avoid all detail and treat his subjects only in outline, but that every word tell." - S&W*

Comment: But giving a couple of explanations  *(i.e. some words about "why" this is not possible)* is nice too, don't you think ?

Comment: You two should stop arguing and notice that someone else, andyjdavis, posted a *helpful* answer.

Comment: @bmb ... If you require the need to access the name of a variable, you have a design problem...

Comment: @Chacha102, maybe so, but that doesn't mean it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Good Idea ? No

Any usecase you where you *should* do it ? No

Proof of concept ? Sure !

```
<?php

a($test);


function a($x) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $file = file($trace[0]['file']);
    $line = $file[$trace[0]['line']-1];

    var_dump($line); // Prints "a($test);" Do the Stringparsing and your done

}
```

Yes, this takes the "easy" by reading the sourcefile, it is also doable by using a php extension called "bytekit" that gives you userland access to the php opcodes and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

No.

When you define a function, you specify a local variable name for it to have inside the scope of that function.  PHP will pass the function the appropriate value, but the symbol is no longer in scope.

You could look into using "[variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)" as an alternative, however.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it *is* possible for sufficiently high values of crazy.

The comments on this page include several techniques:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

lucas dot karisny at linuxmail dot org's answer works on my machine:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php#49997

YMMV.