# How can I get the name of a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I got several variables. One variable contains a string, one an object, and one an array.

```
$mystring = "hello im input";
$myobject = new userclass;
$myarray  = array ( 0 => 'zero', 1 => "one");
```

I want to create an array containing the variable names as key and the values as values, so I then can send this array to a function.

The expected result would be:

```
$multi_array = array (
    'mystring' => "hello im input",
    'myobject' => new userclass,
    'myarray'  => array ( 0 => 'zero', 1 => "one")
)
```

I use the key to get the name of the array and `getclass()` to get the name of the object. But how can I get the name of the variable?

```
function i_do_extract($multi_array) {
   extract($multi_array);
   // Do Rest
}
```

Comment: *Duplicate* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you, but you can use:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

To list defined variables. Remember PHP does support things like

```
$str = "test";
$test = "hmmm";
echo $$str;
```

Which would output `hmmm`.