# Variable Name as string

Tags: php, variables

I need the variable name as string so that I can use it.

For example:

```
$name = "Some Name";
echo "The name of the variable that holds the name is ".findname($name);

function findname($variable) {

 //how to find the name of the variable

 return ?;
}
```

Comment: ... Uh, you already know it's `"name"`...

Comment: In my case the variable name is also dynamic, so I am not sure. I just gave an example to simplify things

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Following on from Ignacio, if you can access the contents of the variable, you can get the name. If it's a dynamic variable name: `$$varname` then the name is found in `$varname`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)