# How to get the variable/const name programatically in PHP?

Tags: php

`func(CONST_A)` should return `'CONST_A'`, `func($name)` should return `$name`

How to implement this `func` in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

Comment: @Marc, it works with variables,but not for CONSTANTS...

Comment: Set up another function and work off the data returned from `get_defined_constants()`. As far as I know, there is no way for a function tell if an argument it's given came from a variable or a constant. It only sees the contents of the var/constant, and nothing of the source. YOu'd have to set up two functions two do what you want. one for vars, one for consts.

Comment: And that solution won't work at all if the thing passed is a literal instead of a variable or constant.  Can you tell us *why* you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible easily.

You can use [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) to determine the [parameters of the function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php), but that returns the variable names that the function expects, and if you're already inside the function, you kind of already know those.

[`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) is the usual way of peeking at what called you, but it returns the *values* of the passed arguments, not the variable names or constants that the caller used when making the call.

However, what it *does* give you is the file name and line number of the caller, so you *could* open up the file and seek to that line and parse it out, but that would be *very silly* and you should not do this.  I am not going to give you example code for this, as it is so utterly silly that you should not consider doing it *ever*.

The `get_defined_vars` thing is a hack and is not guaranteed to work either, and definitely won't work for constants, as [`get_defined_constants`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) does that.

Comment: You are calling me utterly silly.  Well, the fact is that I do that in a cool function for object inspection that I use all the time.  It's not for production environment, I admit it, but let me tell you it's really handy for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function getVarConst($var)
{
    if (isset($GLOBALS[$var]) // check if there is a variable by the name of $var
    {
        return $GLOBALS[$var]; // return the variable, as it exists
    }
    else if (defined($var)) // the variable didn't exist, check if there's a constant called $var
    {
        return constant($var); // return the constant, as it exists
    }
    else
    {
        return false; // return false, as neither a constant nor a variable by the name of $var exists
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not working for const, try `define('CONST_A', 'test');echo getVarConst(CONST_A);`

Comment: The names must be passed as strings. If you pass them as variables or constants, the function receives the value of the constant / variable. As far as I know, it's impossible to get the name of a constant or a variable from it's value, unless you loop through both $GLOBALS and get_defined_constants() looking for the values, and that'd be very stupid - PHP is executed on every request (parsed too, if you don't use an opcode cache). It'd make your app / script perform so bad, it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: To be honest, you shouldn't need this code unless your app needs to be able to get the value of a setting, no matter if the user defined it as a constant or a variable.
E.g. you'd use it to make this work so `$db = 'myDb';` or `define('db', 'myDb');` would both be able to be used, with you abstracting through `getVarConst('db');` so you get the available value, with variable prioritised over constant.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.

You literally want the following right?

```
 define('CONST_A', 'THIS COULD BE ANYTHING');
 $name = 'who cares';

 func(CONST_A); //returns 'CONST_A'
 func($name);   //returns '$name'
```

The function can't know that.

I suppose that reading the source code like Charles describes could get you this, but why?

Comment: Even then, it probably wouldn't be able to work out things like `$name = myFunc('hiThere');` or the like without executing the file. 
In other words, OP's problem is pretty much impossible, definitely not viable in a live environment because of the performance hit and no way it can't be solved through a little refactoring... Well planned apps should never need this kind of thing.