# What is dInspect and how can I use it?

Tags: php

I am very interested in @Sebastián Grignoli 's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php) but, when I try to execute it, I get `Fatal error: Class 'dInspect' not found`.

Can anyone tell me how to rectify this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm at work now, but I'll post it here later today.

Comment: What about that answer is it that you need?
Do you just want to modify that code to make it work and grab the name of the passed variable?  
Or do you want the actual dInspect library to inspect your objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I google it, the first hit is a reference to the NuSphere debugger nusphere.com/products/php_debugger.htm since I don't have that, it looks like I am SOL.

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with the Nusphere debugger.  I never heard of it before.  

I updated the original answer to avoid the confusing function call.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it's some class he made. I googled and the only thing that comes up for "php dInspect" is this question..I also looked for member functions called "dump" in php-included libraries and found nothing.

You might be able to modify his answer a bit to get what you want, it looks pretty complete. (I didn't test anything though)

Comment: Agreed, couldn't find anything about `dInspect`.

Comment: Strange, because when I google it, the first hit is a reference to the NuSphere debugger  http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_debugger.htm   since O don't have that, it looks like I am SOL

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of the solution.  Maybe you could adapt it to your needs with less trouble:

```
function catch_param($label)
{
        $bt = debug_backtrace();
        $src = file($bt[0]["file"]);
        $line = $src[ $bt[0]['line'] - 1 ];

        // let's match the function call and the last closing bracket
        preg_match( "#catch_param\((.+)\)#", $line, $match );

        /* let's count brackets to see how many of them actually belongs 
           to the var name
           Eg:   die(catch_param($this->getUser()->hasCredential("delete")));
                  We want:       $this->getUser()->hasCredential("delete")
        */
        $max = strlen($match[1]);
        $varname = "";
        $c = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
            if(     $match[1]{$i} == "(" ) $c++;
            elseif( $match[1]{$i} == ")" ) $c--;
            if($c < 0) break;
            $varname .=  $match[1]{$i};
        }

    // $varname now holds the name of the passed variable ('$' included)
    // Eg:   catch_param($hello) 
    //             => $varname = "$hello"
    // or the whole expression evaluated
    // Eg:   catch_param($this->getUser()->hasCredential("delete"))
    //             => $varname = "$this->getUser()->hasCredential(\"delete\")"

    echo("The passed expression is: ".$varname);

}
```

If what you want is the inspection class, this is the download link:

http://download.inspect.jaku.com.ar/

Here's an example of the inspector function (and my dInspect class) in action:

http://inspect.jaku.com.ar/

Texts are in spanish in that page, but code is concise and really easy to understand.