# Find largest integer from a set of variables in PHP?

Tags: php, count, integer

I have the following variables:

```
$a = 100;
$b = 200;
$c = 300;
```

Now, I'd basically like to be able to **check the values of $a, $b and $c** and ultimately output something like **"$c is 300 and therefore the largest"**.

How do I achieve this using PHP?

Comment: Better if your values were in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work even with negative values:

```
$a = 100;
$b = 200;
$c = -300;
$max = max($a,$b,$c);
foreach( array('a','b','c') as $v) {
    if ($$v == $max) {
        echo "\$$v is $max and therefore the largest";
        break;
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
$b is 200 and therefore the largest
```

Comment: +1 Nice ... Probably slightly highjacking the question .. i was trying to answer this and came unstuck on trying to make it as dynamic as possible - is it possible to use the variable `$a` and get its name (ie a) as a string instead of using `array('a','b','c')` ? hope that makes sense ?

Comment: @ManseUK: Have a look at the doc http://php.net/get_defined_vars , but AFAK it isn't always working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 100;
$b = 200;
$c = 300;
$max = "a"
foreach(array("a","b","c") as $v){
if($$v > $$max)$max = $v;
}
echo "$max is $$max";
```

Comment: missed on `;` from the `$max=` line (line4) and your output is `c is $c` -> http://codepad.org/d5LMDpOl

Comment: Thank you. I'm just trying this just now and will report back :)

Comment: Just to confirm, does this mean I can use $a and $b in my output?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$arr=array("a"=>100,"b"=>200,"c"=>300);

$val = max($arr);

print_r(array_keys($arr, $val));echo "has maximum value ".$val;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 100;
$b = 200;
$c = 300;

$values = compact( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
arsort( $values );

echo '$' . key( $values ) . ' is ' . current( $values ) . ' and therefore the largest';
```

I like this solution as it's pretty neat; definitely aesthetically a good solution. Not sure how it would perform against other solutions on a large amount of variables.

I would definitely recommend you try and get the initial values into an array rather than separate variables to begin with.