# Get variable name from within the called function

Tags: php, reflection

Can I do this, maybe using ReflectionClass ?

```
myprintr($some_object);


function myprintr(){
  foreach(func_get_args() as $key => $arg){

    // here I want to get the name of the passed variable, "some_object"
    // $key seems to be numeric...
  }


}
```

Comment: You can't, unless you use something like debug_backtrace(), and there shouldn't really be any need for you to do so... is this a business requirement? or just exploring PHP?

Comment: I'm trying to create a print_r/var_dump kind of function for my API, and need this name in case the user passes a object and I'm listing the object methods. I want to prepend the variable name to the method names when displaying them, like $object->method...

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Comment: The var name used in the call has no meaning outside of the calling function... I can call myprintr() using $xyz in one place, $abc in another and "hello world" in a third. Most people use phpdocumentor blocks for API docs

Comment: yes, but you know people use print_r a lot, so I think a localized-version of it would be welcome..

Comment: Even with `debug_backtrace()` you can't: http://codepad.org/40nQwFRu

Comment: @PiTheNumber - it's awkward, but you could... use debug_bcktrace() to retrieve the file/line number of the calling function, then read that file to extract the relevant piece of scripted code that made the call and parse it to get the variable name (watching out for call_user_func(), lambdas and variants)... unless it's in an eval block

Comment: Why not just call print_r and use a output buffer to capture it for your API?  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Alex: what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @Casey: I don't need most of the stuff that print_r displays; I just need to list array contents, object property names and values, and object method names with their default arguments as links which link to the documentation page for that method... Anyway I don't think the purpose is important here

Comment: @Alex: [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) will show you the kind of stuff that you seem to be interested in seeing out of the box.

Comment: why r u guys -1-ing me? it's a legitimate question :P

Comment: @Alex because its the first answer in the Related section and when I type in your exact question title into the Search box I get multiple questions asking the same, e.g. you didnt research properly.

Comment: But there are no answers there that show how to do this..

Comment: @Alex because its impossible. well, unless you want to use `debug_backtrace` to find where the function was called, load that file into a php parser and tokenize the source code to return the variable name (given that there is a variable name at all)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255312/1255289)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user passes an object to myprintr(), then you can use

```
if (is_object($arg)) {
    $className = get_class($arg);
}
```

to get the name of the object type that has been passed, which you can then feed to reflection

but the reflection constructor will accept either a class name *or* an object as an argument, so you don't even need the class name to instantiate a reflection class

**EDIT**

Just for the sake of playing a bit with this concept (and not creating any dependency on globals), or on whether the arguments are variables, values returned from functions, strings, etc:

```
class Test{};

function myTest() {
    $some_object = new Test();
    myprintr($some_object);
}

function myprintr(){
    $callStack = debug_backtrace();
    $calledAt = $callStack[0];

    $callingFile = file($calledAt['file'],FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $callingLine = $callingFile[$calledAt['line']-1];
    $callingLine = substr($callingLine,strpos($callingLine,__METHOD__));
    $calledWithArgNames = trim(substr($matches[0],1,-1));

    var_dump($calledWithArgNames);

    $args = func_get_args();

    foreach($args as $arg) {
        var_dump($arg);
    }
}

myTest();

$some_object = new Test();
$some_other_object = &$some_object;

$t = 2;
$gazebo = "summer house";
$visigoth = pi() / 2; myprintr($some_other_object,pi(), atan2(pi(),$t), $visigoth, "Hello $t World", $gazebo); $t = log($t/$visigoth);
```

This retrieves all the arguments passed by the calling function in $calledWithArgNames, so for the first call you have:

```
'$some_object'
```

and for the second call:

```
'$some_other_object,pi(), atan2(pi(),$t), $visigoth, "Hello $t World", $gazebo'
```

This still requires splitting down into the individual arguments (a preg_split on commas, except where they're inside braces), but is certainly a step closer to what you're actually asking for.

Comment: I'm using this already as a prefix for static methods. For non-static methods I wanted to display that variable name, but if it's not possible I'' just use the class name ..

Answer (score 6):

You cannot get the name of the "variable", as there is no variable.

eg:

```
myprintr("test");
myprintr(myotherfun());
```

Note: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but I just feels terrifyingly wrong.. the whole point of functions and objects is to create barriers, and it shouldn't matter what is in the caller's context..

Comment: @PiTheNumber: that only works with globals... and if the objects is stored in multiple variables, how would you know which one to pick?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access argument names that don't exist: `myprintr` doesn't specify any variable names, and `func_get_args()` will only ever return a numerically indexed array.

I *suppose* you could add docblock comments and access them with reflection, but this seems like an extraordinary amount of overhead for functionality that you *most likely don't need anyway.* Using reflection on the function's arguments itself won't do anything for you because, again, you didn't specify any arguments in the function's argument signature.

PHP function arguments are ordered. They aren't something you can reference like an associative array. If you want access to "associative" type key names for a function or method's arguments, you'll have to specify an array argument and pass a value with the associative keys you want, like this:

```
myfunc(array $args=[])
{
  $key1 = isset($args['key1']) ? $args['key1'] : NULL;
  $key2 = isset($args['key2']) ? $args['key2'] : NULL;
}
```

Comment: I'm in this to learn as well, so please let me know what's wrong with the answer when you downvote. Especially if there's a problem, that way it can be amended or removed. Thanks, retroactively, for being zero help.

Comment: Nothing as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an object you can use [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) and [spl_object_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) to identify the object and then search it in $GLOBALS. There you find the name.

```
class Test{};
$some_object = new Test();
myprintr($some_object);

function myprintr(){
  $args = func_get_args();
  $id = spl_object_hash($args[0]);
  foreach($GLOBALS as $name => $value)
  {
     if (is_object($value) && spl_object_hash($value) == $id) echo $name;
  }
}
```

http://codepad.org/gLAmI511

Comment: what if the object isn't defined in $GLOBALS?

Comment: @Alex - only works if the object is defined in $GLOBALS, forget about using it if the object is instantiated in a function or another object method in your code - http://codepad.org/NlwIdR9N

Comment: @PiTheNumber - getDefinedVars within the myprintr() function will only return varibles that are in scope within that function

Comment: @PiTheNumber: that only works with globals... and even then, if the objects is stored in multiple variables, how would you know which one to pick?

Comment: Knock yourself out with: $some_object = new Test();
$some_other_object = &$some_object;

myprintr($some_other_object);

Comment: Yes I know it does not work always. But it's still fun that it is possible at all. :)