# Can a PHP variable know its name?

Tags: php, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

Example:

Can something like this be achieved in PHP?

```
$Age = 43;

output_variable_name_and_value($Age);

    /*
    outputs:
    "The requested variable name is Age and its current value is 43"; 
    */


//If possible, how would the line marked below with ? ? ? ? be?

function output__variable_name_and_value($input)

{

    $var_name = get_name_somehow($input);   // ? ? ? ? 

    echo "The requested variable name is {$var_name} 
          and its current value is {$input}";

}
```

Comment: Please make sure you code works

Comment: From the accepted answer to the duplicate question: "to be clear, there is no good way to do this in PHP, which is probably because you shouldn't have to do it. There are probably better ways of doing what you're trying to do."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, easily. You have to use $GLOBALS;

```
function get_variable_name($var) {
    foreach($GLOBALS as $k => $v) {
        if ($v === $var) {
            return $k;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The only downfall is, it may return a different variable name if they both have the same value.

Or this,

```
function varName( $v ) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $vLine = file( __FILE__ );
    $fLine = $vLine[ $trace[0]['line'] - 1 ];
    preg_match( "#\\$(\w+)#", $fLine, $match );
    print_r( $match );
}
```

which I found here: [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
function var_name(&$iVar, &$aDefinedVars) {
    foreach ($aDefinedVars as $k=>$v)
        $aDefinedVars_0[$k] = $v;

    $iVarSave = $iVar;
    $iVar     =!$iVar;

    $aDiffKeys = array_keys (array_diff_assoc ($aDefinedVars_0, $aDefinedVars));
    $iVar      = $iVarSave;

    return $aDiffKeys[0];
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var_name($Age, get_defined_vars());
```

<sup>Source: http://mach13.com/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Well..

You can figure out what called the `output__variable_name_and_value` function using debug_backtrace.

Then you know a filename and line number, so you could try to parse the sourcefile and figure out whats between `output__variable_name_and_value(` and `)`.

Probably a bad idea though!