# Get variable name in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

In the below code, how do I check if `$variable` equals "$one".

```
<?php  
    $one = array (1,2,3);
    $two = array (4,5,6);

    $variables = array ($one, $two);

    foreach ($variables as $variable){
        //check if the $variable is equal to "$one"
            //do stuff that is specific for array $one
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to just check if $variable is equal to $one or no? `if($variable == $one) { //Do things }`

Comment: `$variable == $one` does this not work for you. Array can be compared as variables

Comment: Do you have the ability to place indexes of the array values: `'one' => $one, 'two' => $two`...

Comment: @Nikola Do you want to check if $one is equal to $two?

Comment: This question doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Please clarify what you are trying to do exactly and why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255312/1255289)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. You can add a key to the values though:

```
<?php  
$one = array (1,2,3);
$two = array (4,5,6);

$variables = array ( 'one' => $one, 'two' => $two);

foreach ($variables as $key => $variable){
    //check if the $variable is equal to "$one"
    if( $key === 'one' ) {
        //do stuff that is specific for array $one
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this not a viable alternative to getting the name of a variable?

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

For more information visit [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
<?php  
    $one = array (1,2,3);
    $two = array (4,5,6);

    $variables = array ($one, $two);

    foreach ($variables as $variable){
        //check if the $variable is equal to "$one"
           if($variable === $one)
            //do stuff
    }   
?>
```

Comment: `$three = array (1,2,3); $variables[] = $three;`. That will execute the `// do stuff` twice.

Comment: if this is really what the OP wants, the question should be closed because it's not a real question asking how to do an IF block.

Answer (score 1):

```
  foreach ($variables as $variable){
        if($variable == $one)//TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.
        {

        }
    }
```

And if you want to check for order and types as well you can do as follow:

```
  foreach ($variables as $variable){
        if($variable === $one)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with

```
if($variable===$one)
```

You are taking multi dimensional array. Keep in mind and you need to check with "===", not with "==" because its not an variable or even a string.