# Get function variables on included file

Tags: php, function, variables, parameters, include

I have a function like this:

```
function form($filename){
    $text="";
    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/other/".$filename)){
        ob_start();
        include "other/".$filename;
        $text = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $text;
}
```

And, somewhere in my code, I have something like that:

```
class First {
    public function execute()
        $an_array=array("hi","goodbye");
        return form("my_form.php");
}
```

Now I would like to know how I could get the values of `$an_array` on my "my_form.php".
The function `form` is to be used with other files that could need more then one variable.

**EDIT**

I want that the included file could read more then one parameter. In other words, on some other class, I could have something like this:

```
class Second {
    public function execute()
        $first_array=array("hi","goodbye");
        $second_array=array("other","another");
        return form("another_form.php");
}
```

In this case, I would like to read both `$first_array` and `$second_array` on my `another_form.php` file.

**EDIT 2**

Is there any way to make my `form` function work like php's `array_push` function? In other words, I want to have a second parameter on `form` that acts like the last parameter of `array_push`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function form($filename, $special = array()){
    $text="";
    $FILE = $filename;
    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/other/".$filename)){
        ob_start();
        include $FILE; 
        $text = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $text;
}


class Copy {
    public function execute() {
        $array = array();
        $array['first_array'] = array( "first", "second" );
        $array['second_array'] = array( "third", "fourth" );
        return form("my_form.php", $array);
    }
}

$copy = new Copy();
echo $copy->execute();
```

This way you can pass more than one parameter. `$special` will be available in my_form.php and will look like this:

```
Array (
    [first_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => second
        )

    [second_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => third
            [1] => fourth
        )

)
```

**UPDATE:**

You could do it this way, if you don't want to change the variable names

```
function form($filename, $special = array()){
    $text = '';
    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/other/".$filename)){
        extract($special);
        ob_start();
        include $FILE; 
        $text = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $text;
}


class Copy {
    public function execute() {
        return form("my_form.php", array(
                                'var1' => 'test',
                                'var2' => 'test2'
                                ));
    }
}

$copy = new Copy();
echo $copy->execute();
```

In your `my_form.php` your variables will be available

```
echo $var1; // test
echo $var2; // test2
```

Comment: Hmm, I see. But there's no way to the parameter `$special` be dynamic? In other words, something that let me call `form("my_form.php", $array, $array_2, $var_3...)`

Comment: Is is dynamic right now. You can pass as many arrays into the `$array` as you want?

Comment: Yes, I know. But I would prefer if my variables still the same instead of being inside a 'parent' array. In other words, I want something like what php `array_push` does with the last parameter.

Comment: Hmm, I see. There's no way to do that with `func_get_args()` because I can't get the names of the variables passed as parameters right?

Comment: no you can't, you just get the values of the parameters your passed. That's why I used [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), which will keep the name & value.

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php#answer-404637). Is it to bad to read the variables this way?

Comment: Why would you even want to use it? What's wrong with my updated code? It worked fine for me. You just have to be careful to not overwrite variables (if you pass a lot of them to `my_form.php`).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. I just thought that it would be more easy to call something like `form("filename.php",$var_1,$var_2)` then `form("filename.php",array ("var_1"=>$var_1,"var_2"=>$var_2)` in case that someone else needs to use my function.

Comment: I don't see any difference, except the kind of writing. `form("filename.php",$var_1, $var_2..)` won't be possible if you want to have your function dynamic. The only way to do it is to pass all variables in an array (like I did first) or my second approach.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the long chat. I just wanted to be sure that there's no way to do `form("filename.php",$var_1, $var_2..)` with less time consuption. Thank you very much. =)

Comment: No worries, we're here to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

**NASTY ONE**

```
<?php

function form($filename){
    $text = '';
    $FILE = dirname(__FILE__)."/other/".$filename;
    $SPECIALVARS = func_get_args();
    $allVars = explode(',', $SPECIALVARS[1]);
    foreach( $allVars as &$AV ) { $AV = trim($AV); }

    foreach( $SPECIALVARS as $k => $v ) {
        if( $k > 1 ) {
            $theKey = $k-2;
            $_tmp = str_replace('$', '', $allVars[$theKey]);
            // var_dump($_tmp);
            $$_tmp = $v;
        }
    }
    // var_dump($first_array); // now we have it
    if (file_exists($FILE)){
        ob_start();
        include $FILE; // here you can use your vars
        $text = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $text;
}

class Copy {
    public function execute() {
        $an_array = array( "hi", "goodbye" );
        return form("my_form.php", '$an_array', $an_array);
    }
}

class Second {
    public function execute() {
        $first_array = array( "hi", "goodbye" );
        $second_array = array( "other", "another" );
        return form("another_form.php", '$first_array, $second_array', $first_array, $second_array);
    }
}

$s = new Second;    
$s->execute();
```

Comment: How should I get the variables content in `another_form.php`? Do I need to call `$SPECIALVARS[1]` to get `$first_array` value?

Comment: You can also make a hack! ;)

Comment: How could I make a hack in order to call them with the same name they were passed?

Comment: That's the point. Now you can do that, but you also must send names. `return form("another_form.php", '$first_array, $second_array', $first_array, $second_array);`. Check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

file: test.php

```
include "funcs.php";

class Copy {
    public function execute()
    {
        $an_array=array("hi","goodbye");
        return form("my_form.php",$an_array);
    }
}

$f=new Copy();
echo $f->execute();
?>
```

file: funcs.php

```
<?php
function form($filename, $params){
    $text="";
    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/other/".$filename)){
        ob_start();
        include "other/".$filename;
        $text = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $text;
}

?>
```

file: other/my_form.php

```
<?php
print_r($params);
?>
```

Comment: But what if I have more then one parameter to send to `form`?

Comment: See my edit for an example of what I was trying to say on my first comment