# PHP - how to get a variable's name?

Tags: php, variables, namespaces

I want to make a little function for debugging purposes, that prints the contents of the variable in a human readable format.

The function is based on the `pr()` shortcut found in CakePHP framework, i.e. [this one](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-function-pr.html#214-228):

I have this so far:

```
function pr($var,$msg){
    $pr_debug=true;
    if($pr_debug){
        echo "<pre>";
        if($msg) echo "<b>".$msg.": </b>";
        if(gettype($var)=="array" || gettype($var)=="object" ) echo "<br>";
        print_r($var);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

which prints an optional message  ($msg) before the variables content.

But what I want to add, is that if no message is sent, to also print the variable's NAME as such message, so i could get something like this:

```
$myvar="hello";
pr($myvar);
```

//should output:

```
myvar: hello
```

So inside my function, how can I get the variable's name as a string so I can output it?
i.e. with `pr($foo);` I need `"foo"`, 
`$name="biz"; pr($$name);` I need `"biz",`
and so on...

Preferably I want something that would work despite PHP globals configuration or any of that (which by the way I don't understand very well, so any help on GLOBALS stuff would be much appreciated).

Thanks!

Extra: here at stackoverflow, how do i format source code to get PHP formatting and colors? As of now, I simpy used the toolbar in the textarea and chose "code sample"...

Comment: You should accept a string as input instead of a variable, then use `$$var` to get the value of the variable and `$var` to get the name of the variable.

Comment: Realize that when you have a function `function foo($a)`, `$a` may have originally been the return value from a function, an algebraic expression, a literal value, or any number of things which aren't named variables.

Comment: I've tried to outline some of the reasons why this isn't such a useful idea on the older question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15936154/157957

Answer (score 1):

What you want is variable variables... but in truth, you do NOT want them. They're almost as bad as "goto" in modern programing:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$baz = 'foo';
echo $$baz;   // bar
     ^^-- note the doubled $'s
```

Problem is, by the time you get to your debug code, the "source" of the varaible's name has been lost, e.g.

```
function debug($out) {
   global $$out;
   echo $out, ': ', $$out;
}

$foo = 'bar';
debug($foo);
```

this will not output "foo" as the name, because the name '$foo' was not passed in to the function. Only the VALUE of `$foo`, which is `bar` goes in.

Comment: but if instead of calling debug($foo) i call it as debug("foo"), then it will work as expected, echoing "foo: bar", which is what i want! so, instead of passing a $var directly as the parameter, I only need to modify my function to receive a variable's NAME, as a string, and then use it with $$ to get it's content. Am I right?

Comment: yes, but remember that within the function, that variable would be out of scope anyways.