# PHP get assigned variable name inside anonymous function

Tags: php, function, variables, methods

I know you can find the method name inside a declared method such as:

```
function getFunction() {
    return __METHOD__;
}
echo getFunction(); // 'getFunction'
```

But how do you find the variable name of an anonymous function such as the example below?

```
$anonymous = function() {
    return __VARIABLE__
}
echo $anonymous; // 'anonymous
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You can get the name of the variable (in a somewhat convoluted manner) as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins for curl_multi_init(), which will execute multiple multi-threaded downloads in a loop. I wanted to identify each progress function individually inside the loop.