# Select variable with the highest value

Tags: php

I need to select the largest value between two variables, but not return the value itself. So using `max` won't do the trick.

Example:

```
$value1 = 60;  
$value2 = 24;
```

I need `$value1` (the variable name) to be returned. This would be simpler to do, were the variables in an array as I could do a `foreach` loop to return the key with the highest value, but I don't think there's much point creating an array when there's only every going to be two values, unless it won't effect the efficiency at all (I'm not sure it will).

Comment: This makes no sense. You can't "return a variable"; do you mean, you want to return the *name* of a variable, as in a string? Or a reference to the variable? Show some real code, instead of simply saying "i need Value1 to be returned".

Comment: Can you provide data type? Some example code you've tried?

Comment: Wait. "I need to select the largest value between two variables, **but not return the value itself.**" but then "I need Value1 to be returned." Which is it? Although I'm not sure how you want to get the maximum value if the function doesn't return it like `max()`.

Comment: but where do you have the variables listed to see them?

Comment: if you know there are only going to be 2 values, can't you just use an if statement?

Comment: Take a look a this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Comment: you mean the name of the variable???

Comment: Obviously I meant the name of the variable, that's why you all keep asking the same question. If everyone is asking it, surely that's just common logic?

Comment: @Karl, `$ans = $value1 > $value2 ? '$value1' : '$value2';`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$biggerValue = null;
if ($value1 > $value2){
  $biggerValue = 'value1';
} elseif ($value2 > $value1) {
  $biggerValue = 'value2';
}
```