# "Indirect" isset()

Tags: php

```
function myCheck($in)
      { return isset($in); }

$var1='Something';
$var2='$var1';
$var3='$varNonExitant';
```

What I'm trying to achive is to use `myCheck` to evaluate the existance of the content like this:

```
myCheck($var2) return true;
myCheck($var3) return false;
```

Comment: there is a php function for that. It's called isset! :-)

Comment: @NicholasKing - He's probably aware of it, since he's trying to write a wrapper for it.

Comment: What do you "really" want to do?

Comment: I don't see any question here

Comment: `$var3` will be a string of `"$varNonExitant"` - why should it return false?

Comment: You can just use `if(isset($var2)){...}`, no need to write a wrapper for it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I was being sarcastic :-) why wrap a single function call into a function call? Its pointless and since the question is not even a question it was a statement I thought the comment was warranted.

Comment: Also, I mean to believe you meant to write `$var2 = $var1` and `$var3 = $varnonexistant`.

Comment: C'mon guys, OBVIOUSLY that is a fragment of a longer method..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/255335/358906

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you cyall myCheck($abc), with set $abc = 123, it gets myCheck(123). It isn't any valid argument for isset.

You have to give the function a string with variable name:

```
function isset_global($variable_name)
{
    return isset($GLOBALS[$variable_name]); 
}
```

Of course, I am also wondering, why to do this, but it answers the question as long as you check a global variable.

Comment: This will always fail, since no variable exists inside the function besides `$in`.

Comment: It is a bad idea. You will always got false since `$$in` refers to a variable that does not exist in function scope.

Comment: Note edit. You can use global.

Comment: No, you can not. There's no guarantee that function was called from global context. For example, call was made from a method or another function. You cannot refer to local variables from your custom function then.

Comment: This is, more or less, the correct answer for me. Please see http://3v4l.org/HCXq6

Comment: @Barth Zalewski: this works 100% in my context! Thank you!

Comment: Please note that this requires lowering the error reporting settings [[fiddle](http://3v4l.org/Er9M3)], which kind of beats the purpose of having `isset()` in the first place.

Comment: This answer misses the notice that if the global variable is not set so far, it will be created. Better use `$GLOBALS`.

Answer (score 6):

[isset()](http://php.net/isset) is not really a function: it's a language construct. As such, it's allowed to do some magic that's not available to regular functions, such as being fed with non-existing variables.

To sum up: you cannot replicate it with a custom function.

**Edit:**

As *DaveRandom* [pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183583/indirect-isset/18183671#comment26646093_18183666) below, all you can do is come close by checking if a variable isset for example:

```
function variable_isset(&$variable = NULL) {
    return isset($variable);
}
```

This approach offers two drawbacks though:

1. This works by passing the unset variable by reference, thus creating it when called. As it's NULL it is still not set.
2. It'll trigger an *Undefined variable* notice if the variable does not exist, ruining the whole concept of gracefully handling optional variables.

Most likely this should not be needed. So question remains why you can not use `isset` in the first place which would be much more needed to give you better guidance.

Comment: since when is isset() not a function? its listed in the php docs under functions!

Comment: @Nicholas It says so right there on its manual page...

Comment: @deceze I stand corrected!

Comment: It's worth noting that it *is* possible to replicate `isset()` in the manner shown above - with a caveat. `function wrapped_isset(&$var = null) { return isset($var); }`. This functions exactly like `isset()` and will always return the same results, *however* when the variable didn't exist it will be created an initialised with a value of `null`. It will still return `false` for `isset()` even after this, but it will have been created and will appear, for example, in the list returned by `get_defined_vars()`. However, this is not something I would recommend as (to me at least) it is code smell.