# How do I get the last used variable in PHP?

Tags: php

in bash there is something like

```
$_
```

which is a temporary variable that stores the last argument of previous command

is there **a similar** variable or construct in PHP or how can I access the last used variable in the script?

this would be very handy for simple debugging functions or if you need a function that you have to add in several places at your code.

Or you could add something like:

```
do_some_more($_);
```

in several places in your code

Comment: There isn't such a feature.

Comment: What do you actually want to do, and why?

Comment: What do you need that for ?

Comment: $_ is like perl, put an exemple what are your trying.

Comment: @perdeu I think [$_ in perl](http://perlmaven.com/the-default-variable-of-perl) and [$_ in bash](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/tag/bash-_-variable/) both exist, and do different things...

Comment: `$_` makes sense in bash because you do have commands. But what'd be the PHP equivalent to commands? What does "use a variable" mean? In `list($a, $b) = foo($c, $d+$e);`, what'd be the last used variable?

Comment: What you want to do has no sense. That thing in bash allows you to not to have to re-type stuff to repeat them. There is no such issue in PHP, thanks to what we call functions...

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in PHP.

$_ is just like any other variable.

```
$_ = 'hello world';

echo $_; // hello world
```

Comment: sure, but that was not the question. I tried $_ before I asked here

Comment: @rubo The answer is *"There is no such feature in PHP."*

Comment: I could imagin a construct that finds out with the help of debug_backtrace like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19788805/1069083

Comment: @rubo Maybe so, and if you write a custom PHP extension you may be able to add a "real" `$_` to PHP. But the point is that there's no such thing built in, and as several people pointed out in the comments, the exact function of bash's `$_` is hardly applicable to PHP to begin with.

Comment: How would such a custom PHP extension look like?

Comment: @rubo If you have to ask, don't even go there. And define unambiguously how exactly it should work to begin with (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788891/how-do-i-get-the-last-used-variable-in-php/19788977#comment29415589_19788891).