# PHP: Grab empty parameter name ?123

Tags: php, parameters, url-parameters

How can I grab an empty parameter name in PHP e.g. http://yoursite.com/?123 > "123" ?

I want to use this as URL shortener to redirect to the ID from the parameter.

Comment: Through `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` you can access this.

Comment: Check the answer in this post, problem is simular: http://stackoverflow.com/a/255335/3143634

Answer (score 0):

You have built-in function that will parse your URL [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and string query parser [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```php
$url = 'http://yoursite.com/?123&a=b&abc=';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parsed['query'], $query);
var_dump($query);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/85110)</kbd>

Keys in array `$query` that have empty string as value, are the keys you are looking for.

```php
$filtered = array_filter($query, function($v) { return empty($v); });
#$filtered = array_keys($filtered);
print_r($filtered);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/85120)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but as dimimpou pointed out, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` does just fine. Added is_numeric() and whoop!

Comment: @Martin: I miss-understood the question, I thought you have URL saved in the variable. p.s. What if someone adds some custom parameters to the URL? Like `?test=abc&123` ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then he fails which is fine for being a hacker :)

Comment: @Martin: `hacker`, lol ;) Some links are changed by google or FB, who append there own parameters. You should check that case scenario, and not leave it in the 'air' ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_keys` to fetch all keys.

```
var_dump(array_keys($_GET));

array(1) { 0 => "123" }
```

`"123"` will also appear if you iterate over `$_GET`, like with `foreach`.