# How to replace with preg_replace php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm having an php array like this :

```
$_0xb29b = ['item1','item2','item3'];
```

And I have a text file like this

```
_0xb29b[0] foo foo foo foo foo foo _0xb29b[2]
```

Can You guys show me how to replace `_0xb29b[0]` in the text file with the right item in the array? I want the text tho be like this:

```
item1 foo foo foo foo foo foo item3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback):

```
<?php
// header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$str     = '_0xb29b[0] foo foo foo foo foo foo _0xb29b[2], _0xb29b[xxx]';
$_0xb29b = ['item1','item2','item3', 'xxx' => 5];

$result  = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\_0xb29b\[([^\]]+)\]/',
    function($matches)use($_0xb29b){
        return $_0xb29b[$matches[1]];
    },
    $str
);

echo $result;
?>
```

Shows:

```
item1 foo foo foo foo foo foo item3, 5
```

---

**NOTE:** To get file content as a string I suggest you to read manual on [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file-get-contents).

Comment: @NguyễnĐăngKhoa Can you add an example ?

Comment: How about when it's not only number but also text like _0xb29b[text] and there is an right element in the code ?

Comment: @NguyễnĐăngKhoa Cheers. If any answer of here helped you to resolve your issue, you may mark your issue / question as sloved by accepting answer as the "solution". Take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I spent too much time getting this to work not to post it. Doesn't use preg_match, but pretty much replicates it. First it creates the needle from the variable name. Then, searches for the needles in the haystack using substr_count and strpos. Then uses the positions of the found needles and length of the needle to grab the index of the variable and replace using the array of the variable used to create the needle. Links to all the sources at the bottom.

```
<?php

function print_var_name($var) {
    foreach($GLOBALS as $var_name => $value) {
        if ($value === $var) {
            return $var_name;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$_0xb29b = array('item1','item2','item3');

$needle = print_var_name($_0xb29b);
$needle_length = strlen($needle);
$haystack = '_0xb29b[0] foo foo foo foo foo foo _0xb29b[2]';
$haystack_height = strlen($haystack);

$num_needles = substr_count($haystack,$needle) . '<br />';
if($num_needles>0){
    $offset = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<$num_needles;$i++){
        $needle_pos[$i] = strpos($haystack,$needle,$offset);
        $needle_index[$i] = substr($haystack,$needle_pos[$i]+$needle_length+1,1);
        if($needle_pos[$i]+$needle_length+3<$haystack_height){
            $haystack = substr($haystack,0,$needle_pos[$i]). ' ' .${$needle}[$needle_index[$i]] . ' ' . substr($haystack,$needle_pos[$i]+$needle_length+3);
        } else {
            $haystack = substr($haystack,0,$needle_pos[$i]). ' ' .${$needle}[$needle_index[$i]];
        }
        $offset = $needle_pos[$i]+1;
    }
}
echo $haystack;
?>
```

[Variables variables][1] used to turn the string back into a variable with the issue of the variable being an array and using

```
${$needle}[index]
```

to call the array index.
  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php
  [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

Comment: I see this is a very good method. I learning about your method :)