# Convert a string variable to upper case in php

Tags: php

Is it possible to convert a string variable to upper case. The variable itself and not the content of the variable.

For example :-

```
  $name = "Jam"
  $data = function ?($name);
```

Such that $data contains "NAME". $name is passed as a variable in a function and can be $name or $game or anything. 
The fact of the matter is that I am trying to capitalize the variable name.
Is there anyway that can be achieved in php.

```
  strtoupper($name)
  -->Output : JAM
```

That's not what I want I need the variable to be capitalized. I would appreciate any sort of assistance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: @Matt
I had fields coming from the database which mapped onto my properties, so I wanted to lower the case...

Answer (score 2):

you can use the php **strtoupper()** if you want all of you string to be on the uppercase but if you want only the first letter of the string to uppercase **ucfirst()**

Comment: OP wants to convert the variable name itself and not variable content

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP `strtoupper()` function:

**CODE**

```
<?php

$name = 'Jam';

    echo strtoupper(print_var_name($name));

function print_var_name($var) {
    foreach($GLOBALS as $var_name => $value) {
        if ($value === $var) {
            return $var_name;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
NAME
```

*Adapted from [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php).*

Comment: @UmarAftab Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Matt that's what this does

Comment: @HankyPanky I totally didn't read the full code, 3 hours sleep is not good :D

Answer (score 0):

"... $name is passed as a variable in a function ..." then it changes to the variable name in the function definition - original variable name doesn't matter at that point. <s>So your function never know the variable's name.</s> *** Obviously there is a way for this. Shown in EDIT ***

However, if you want to create a variable as an uppercase version of another variable - which I have no clue what to do with this - then this will do that for you.

```
$name = "Jam";
${strtoupper("name")} = $name;
print $NAME;
```

*** EDIT ***:  I had no idea about this and very strange and converted from the link I posted in my comment and I have still no idea why it could be even used but:

```
function magicfunc($var)
{
   foreach($GLOBALS as $k => $v) { 
       if (!is_array($k) && $v == $var) return(strtoupper($k));
   }
}

$name = "1234";

${magicfunc($name)} = $name;

// Yes, we have this variable
print $NAME;
```

Comment: @Umar Aftab : interesting and I had no idea but please check the last post here: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/3815-convert-variable-name-into-string/

Comment: It actually gave me output 'Jam' after I tried it ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$name = 'Jam';
$vars = get_defined_vars();

foreach ($vars as $key => $var) {
    if ($var == 'Jam') {
        $data = strtoupper($key);
    }
}

echo $data;
```