# PHP how to echo variable name

Tags: php, echo

I'm kinda confused in my case,

```
$counts="$s{$process[$count]}";
```

if i echo $counts with

```
echo "$counts";
```

it still showing the value, how can i echo $counts to show the variable name

> $steamroller

(in this case the process is 'team', and count is 'roller')) instead of the value of the variable $system?

EDIT 
okay i found it by myself it should be

```
$counts='$s'.$process."[".$count."]";
```

thank you..

Comment: Just use `single quotes` instead of `double quotes` in echo `statement` plz check here: https://3v4l.org/VZHG8

Comment: `$counts` or `$count`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Comment: @Ali that's not what i mean, the $steamroller itself is a variable that has a value, so every time i echo $count it always showing the value of $steamroller instead of "$steamroller", the wrong thing i think is how i save the variable in $counts

Comment: @FrayneKonok im sorry sir, i rate up your answer yesterday, maybe my internet connection is down, after i check again this time, my rate up and green check is missing, looks like it wasnt make it, sorry :)

Comment: its okey, just remove the last comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make this:

```
$s = 's';
$count = 1;
$process[$count] = 'teamroller';

echo $counts = "$$s{$process[$count]}"; // $steamroller
```

Answer (score 2):

if you echo variable name in "" , php parse that variable an echo its value,
if you want echo variable name with '' like this:

```
echo '$counts';
```