# Php instance property name to string as Method Parameter

Tags: php, oop, properties

Nowadays i'm trying to develop a php framework for own customers. In my app, I want to pass `$instance->propertyName` as parameter. But don't need `$instance->propertyName` value. Only I want to use propertyName part as string value. Can I take **propertyName** as string?

For example if I have an object `$bar` of the class

```
class foo
{
    public $someProperty1;
    public $someProperty2;
}

$bar = new foo();
```

and if I have another class like

```
class anotherClass
{
    public function someMethod($arg)
    {
        //I need the property name that provide the $arg value in this place
    }
}
```

and when I run this code

```
$someObject = new anotherClass();
$someObject->someMethod($bar->someProperty1); //I want to know the name of property that provide a value to the someMethod method (the 'someProperty1' in this case)
```

then I want to know inside the method `someMethod` in `anotherClass` class the name of the property that provide the `$arg` value. As the result for example above I want to get a string `someProperty1`.

Comment: `$foo = $obj->foo; echo $foo;` If you want to get fancy, then you could do `$foo &= $obj->foo`, so `$foo` updates whenever you change `$obj->foo`

Comment: I don't know what he means, but I don't think that is it.
Do you mean using $instance->$variablePropertyName. Or do you mean converting $instance->propertyName to $propertyName as a variable containing the string "propertName"?

Comment: Thank you but this is not solved my problem. I tried it but result s 0 on my screen.

Comment: Can you try to explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you'll really need to explain more specifically what you're trying to do and show an example of the actual code you're using.

Comment: This my concrete example. My class properties equal my table fields. I am developing a class for table query. With my classes and helpers i am  creating a dynamic sql. For example. $result = $instance->select("*")->from("students")->where("age > 20")->orderBy("age"); In this example not exacly my project but it seems. Now i want to change this code as below  $result = $instance->select("*")->from("students")->where($entity->age > 20)->orderBy($entity->age); To do this work, i need only "age" from this: $entity->age. Or can you suggest any useful method for my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to achive this. You want to know something like this

```
function foo($bar)
{
    //here you want to know the name of the variable that passing the value
}

$x = 5;
$y = 5;

foo($x); //here you want to know the name 'x' of the variable
foo($y); //here you want to know the name 'y' of the variable
```

In both case function will get only information about value `5` and nothig about name of the variable provide the value.

If you want to know the name of the variable (or object property) that provides value into method then you can use something **very inefficient** like this

```
class someClass
{
    public $someProperty;
}

class otherClass
{
    public function setSomething($arg)
    {
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        $vLine = file($trace[0]['file']);
        $fLine = $vLine[$trace[0]['line'] - 1];
        preg_match("/(.*?)\((.*?)->(.*?)\)/i", $fLine, $match);

        var_dump($match[3], $arg);
    }
}

$t = new someClass();
$t->someProperty = 5;

$o = new otherClass();
$o->setSomething($t->someProperty);
```

The `var_dump` in the `setSomething` method will return the name and the value of the property

> string(12) "someProperty" int(5)

This solution is based on idea from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/404637/4662836