# php > get previous variable name

Tags: php

Any direct method to get previous variable name ?

```
$a = "";
$b = "";
if (logic) {
    $result = $a;
} elseif (logic) {
    $result = $b;
}
```

any `direct_function($result)` can get "a" or "b" ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not getting your question. Can you explain briefly?

Comment: When/why is `$result` a or b? Ternary seems like an option.

Comment: i don't know if there's a function that really does this, you want to get the variable name of the last assignment of that main variable. good question though, or even to check whether the assignment is any value, or a variable or whatever, any particular reason why you need this?

Comment: i think you don't even know what you want, please be specific

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense. Can you please explain differently

Comment: maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get your question then i think the Best way is to use an array().
For example:

```
$a = "";
$b = "";
$result=array();     // an empty array
if (logic) {
    $result[] = $a;
} elseif (logic) {
    $result[] = $b;
}
```

Now you can get any value by index.

Comment: I don't understand why this would be any different to what he has. Why is an array useful in this situation? I'm not convinced any of us actually understand the question though... (including the OP)