# how can i print var name instead var value in PHP?

Tags: php

how can i print var name instead var value in php?
Like this code:

```
$Tree = "abcd";
$str = "zwd";
```

i want to print something like this:
tree = abcd
str = zwd

please help me

Comment: of what possible use would this be?vars only exist because YOU wrote them. The only time you'd have arbitrary variable names is if you're doing (stupid) stuff like `extract()`, have `register_globals` on, or are using variable variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

Comment: this could be related to this post: [how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
$array = array('Tree' => 'abcd', 'str' => 'zwd');
foreach ($array as $name => $value) {
    echo $name . ' = ' . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function

```
<?php
    $city  = "San Francisco";
    $state = "CA";
    $event = "SIGGRAPH";

    $location_vars = array("city", "state");

    $result = compact("event", "nothing_here", $location_vars);
    // print_r($result);
?>
```

Then print the key and its value,

```
foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . " : " . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you maybe looking for is

```
echo 'Tree = ' . $Tree;
echo '<br>';
echo 'str = ' . $str;
```

I am pretty sure OP meant above, btw for expert level programmers, Why this question is paradoxical in nature, is lets say you want to print/output the **name** of variable `$xyz`. See....

...did you notice...

....that in order to print the name of a variable you had to actually type the **name** of the variable in the first place! How else would you refer to that variable!!! And for that the above method of concatenation is best suited :)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936154/807104) someone with sane mentality tried to explain better.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print variable names not writing it by yourself you should use `get_defined_vars()` as follow :

```
$var1 = 'I am ';
$what = array_search($var1, get_defined_vars(), true);

printf($var1.'%s', $what); // I am var1
```

Comment: 1. You may have more than one variable with the same value, 2. you’re already writing `$var1`, why bend over backwards like this instead of just hardcoding the name‽

Comment: If there is 2 variables with the same value then you will have to handle 2 differents results. Personnally, I would never do such a thing, I'm just answering the question : there is no other way to get a variable name without writing its name by yourself.