# How to return an Array's "name" as a String

Tags: php

```
$myAry = array();

// I want to return the array's name.

// something like
echo $myAry.name;

// Should print "$myAry".
```

Thanks,

Comment: dude learn the basic of php first or see some tutorial(s)

Comment: What an arrogant comment when one doesn't even know what the person is doing !

Comment: This post solved my issue :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 0):

But if you type `$myAry` you already know the name of the variable. What is
it  you are trying to achieve?

If you absolutely must know the identity of your variables...

```
function my_function ($my_array) {
    $caller_info = array_shift(debug_backtrace());
    $lines = file($caller_info['file']);
    $line = $lines[$caller_info['line'] - 1];
    if(preg_match('/my_function\\s*\\(\$(\\w+)/', $line, $matches)) {
        $name_of_my_array = $matches[1];
        echo $name_of_my_array;
    }

}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you, this is close, but it returns only the my_function's arg name(e.g. $my_array) every time, no matter what array is passed, and not what the arg is referring to. 
Example: if I use it like this 
    my_function($new_name) 
It should return a string "$new_name" not "$my_array" as it does every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get argument name like this:

```
function get_function ($my_array) {
    $f = new ReflectionFunction($my_array);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($f->getParameters() as $param) {
        $result[] = $param->name;   
    }
    return $result;

}

function sayHello($helloWorlds){
    echo $helloWorld;
}

print_r(get_function('sayHello'));;


 //Output
 Array ( [0] => helloWorlds )
```

Comment: Not looking for elements.

Comment: @SpaceCorpSolutions find a solution for your problem, Please Check.

Answer (score 0):

$array = array('name12');
 $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // name12

// Empty string when using an empty array:

var_dump(implode('hello', array())); // string(0) ""

Comment: Not looking for elements.