# Get the name of his own variable? PHP ${$var}

Tags: php, function, var

I want the variable name from example: `${'tell'.$var.'How}`. I've tried a couple of the examples `varName();` from [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255312/5788509), but I didn't get it working. Any idea how to get this working?

```
<?php
    $var = 'Me';
    ${'tell'.$var.'How'} = 'Thanks!';
    $name = varName(${'tell'.$var.'How'});

    // Varialbe name: $tellMeHow = Thanks! 
    echo 'Variable name: $'.$name.' = '.${'tell'.$var.'How'}; 
?>
```

Function:

```
<?php
    function varName($v) {
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        $vLine = file( __FILE__ );
        $fLine = $vLine[ $trace[0]['line'] - 1 ];
        preg_match( "#\\$(\w+)#", $fLine, $match );
        return $match[1];
    }
?>
```

Is it possible that a variable is its own name?

```
<?php
    $var = 'is my name '.varName().'?';
    echo $var; // is my name var?

    $why = 'Why '.$var;
    echo $why; // Why is my name var?
?>
```

Cool if someone knows this... and what's to tell me. ;)

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? What is the result now and what is your expected result

Comment: You passing $v into `varName()` which doesn't do anything.  But in your last example you don't pass anything, which causes an error.

Answer (score -1):

These are known as "[variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)" and are described in the PHP documentation.

Comment: @NgoTuan, my answer already provides that link if you click on "variable variables".

Comment: Perhaps the person who downvoted my answer could explain why they did so?