# loop variable and function names php

Tags: php, function, loops, variables, names

Let's say that I have a php file.
In it, I have some variables and some functions. For example:

```
$results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
printResults($results);

function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
  return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '3daysAgo',
       '2daysAgo',
       'ga:sessions');
}
```

and

```
function printResults($results) {
  if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

    $profileName = $result->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

    $rows = $results->getRows();
    $sessions = $rows[0][0];

    // Print the results.
    print $sessions;
  } else {
    print "No results found.\n";
  }
}
```

Now, how could I loop through these, changing both variable and function names dynamically?

So (pseudocode, hope it is clear what it is trying to do)

```
for($i=2; $i<30; $i++){
    $results = $results$i = getResults$i($analytics, $profile);
    printResults$i($results$i);

    function getResults$i($analytics, $profileId){
    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    $i'daysAgo',
    ($i+1)'daysAgo,
    'ga:sessions');
    }
}
```

meaning that `$results` becomes `$results2`, `$results3`, etc 
and
`getResults()` becomes `getResults2()`, `getResults3()`, etc
and
'`3daysAgo`' becomes `4daysAgo`, `5daysAgo`, etc.

Can it be done?

Comment: Do you want to create dynamic functions? May I know the reason because I am not getting why you want dynamic multiple methods although one method can work perfectly.

Comment: Why do you want to create variables that you cannot access the usual way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change variable name using this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255335/3179389):

```
   function get_var_name($var) {
        foreach($GLOBALS as $var_name => $value) {
            if ($value === $var) {
                return $var_name;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

and if you want to change variable name `$request` with `$request1` you can do:

```
${get_var_name($request).'1'} = $request;
```

and if you want to create function dynamically:

```
  $function = create_function("/* comma separated arguments*/", "/*code as string*/);
```

and call it:

```
$function();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an array to store the results:

```
$results_array = array();
```

then we can use an array of functions params to pass (just as an example - not your script):

```
$data = array(
    'one' => array('param1' => $some_data, 'param2' => $some_other_data),
    'two' => array('param1' => $more_data, 'param2' => $some_more_data),
);

foreach ($data as $k => $v)
{
     $results_array[] = my_fnc_name($v['param1'], $v['param2']);
}
```

this will add in (via a numeric index) the function return value into `$results_array`

Answer (score 0):

**#Using lambda function**

```
$printResults$i= function($analytics, $profile) {
    //perform your logic
};

call_user_func_array($printResults$i, array($analytics, $profile));
```

[Ref :: call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)