# covert array multidimensional array to one dimensional array

Tags: php

I have array and i need return format: [1,2,3]

```
$a = [1,2,3];
print_r( $a );
// result: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

I had used json_encode but it only return "[1,2,3]"
. And I need return $a = [1,2,3];

So how to process return that format [1,2,3]

Comment: It looks like the array is already in the desired format. Are you misinterpreting the `print_r` formatting? Do you mean you want to print it like `echo "$a = [" . implode(', ', $a) . "]";`? Or do you want the variable name `$a` in the output?

Comment: I had used json_encode but it only return "[1,2,3]" . And I need return $a = [1,2,3];

Comment: See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Comment: But i have more issue. Data origin is "1,2,3" how to convert to [1,2,3]

Comment: `explode(",", $data);`

Comment: I tried your way and it returns [1,2,3]. But when I create an object:
$ newObj = new stdclass;
$newObj -> attr = $a;
It return "[1,2,3]"

Comment: It seems like you keep moving the goalpost. You'll need to edit your question to clearly state what your expected input and output is and the transformation you're trying to perform, and where you're stuck. Otherwise, I'm pretty confused about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yeah, also, give more info, WHY do you need it this way, where are you gonna use this array is not clear what you need neither what you need it for.