# How to print name of the variable which stores an array in php?

Tags: php

I want to print the array identifier name along with its content.
In situations where a page contains many arrays, then there is a confusion -
which elements belong to which array.

```
$user= array('id' => 1,'name' => "Tom");

//expectation
user
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Tom
)
```

Comment: Thiis [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php) may help you