# Can you echo/print a $variable name passed into a function?

Tags: php

Let's say I have a function that is passed a string:

```
function foo($var) {
    echo 'Variable Passed: ' . ???
}
```

I want to print/access the `???` part, so when using the function, I could print the actual string name passed:

```
foo($myStringName);

Variable Passed: $myStringName
```

Does PHP have a way of doing the ??? part?

Comment: What do you mean by `???`

Comment: Do you want to print the variable name?

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to print the name of the variable that was passed to the function, while the function is executing. So if I do foo($stringName) it would execute as Variable Passed: $stringName

Comment: The name can’t be changed, so it’s ‘$var’. AFAIK there is no “nameof” operator in PHP. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/255312/2864740 (all the presented methods are various hacks that should probably be limited to specific debugging contexts)

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much but figured thought there might be a clever way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `$GLOBALS` variable and check for matching variable name as the one passed

```
function printVarName($var) {
    foreach($GLOBALS as $varName => $val) {
        if ($val === $var) {
            echo 'Variable Passed: $'.$varName;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$vars = 1;
printVarName($vars); //prints Variable Passed: $vars
```

Comment: Interesting and cool, but sadly sadly not what I'm after. I don't think what I want to do is possible, but I've found a different way of solving my problem, thanks anyway.