# How can I link a variable name into activity log description? Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, laravel, logging, android-activity

```
<h6 class="mb-0">Collections / {{$establishment->category->name}} / {{ $establishment->name }}</h6>
        @php
        $en = $establishment->name;
            activity()->log( '$en' );
        @endphp
```

how can I put the establishment name into the activity log description?

Comment: the code is in a blade.php

Comment: Why do you need to see $en in your activity log? Isn't it enough to write it like interpolation? `'$en: ' . $en`

Comment: Because I want to put the establishment name into activity vlog description.

Comment: I am creating a hotel recommender system, and I am using collaborative filtering.

Comment: If you really need to get name of variable, then this issue could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php

Comment: "You want to put the establishment name into activity vlog". Isn't it this `$establishment->name`?? Why not `activity()->log($establishment->name)` ? I don't understand it clearly.